# What this parameter does "-XX:+UseInterpreter"?

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-arguments

I was wondering what this parameter does **-XX:+UseInterpreter**,
I did some research on the internet and i found that

> Use interpreter for non-compiled methods

I just don't understand what this parameter really does, can someone explain to me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-XX:+UseInterpreter` is ON by default, so this option does nothing.

If you turn it off by `-XX:-UseInterpreter`, every time a new method is called, it will be added to a compilation queue. This option alone is almost useless. However, it serves as a part of `-Xcomp` flag, which is basically a shortcut for

```
-XX:-UseInterpreter
-XX:-BackgroundCompilation
-XX:-ClipInlining
-XX:Tier3InvokeNotifyFreqLog=0
-XX:Tier4InvocationThreshold=0
```

In this case JVM will not run Java methods in interpreter, i.e. methods will be forcibly JIT-compiled before use.

Comment: can you explain with some example? i still don't understand

Comment: @Emax JVM may execute Java code in 3 modes: 1) `-Xint` - the bytecode is interpreted; 2) `-Xcomp` - Java methods are compiled to machine code on the first execution; 3) mixed (the default) - methods start execution in interpreter and later hot methods are compiled. `-XX:-UseInterpreter` option forces compilation of all Java methods on the first execution.